# Using a method result in as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model

Right now I have the following in my as_json method in a model:

```
  #values we will pass to Json
  def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:name, :last_name, :age])
  end
```

I have a method that does some logic and returns a value:

```
def self.full_name
 self.name + self.last_name
end
```

How can I return the "options" result in the as_json along with the fields that I already have? I have tried this:

```
#values we will pass to Json
  def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:name, :full_name => self.full_name, :last_name, :age])
  end
```

With no luck.

Comment: What does self.options return?

Comment: yeah.. its not clear what you want...

Comment: self.options can return whatever, I just want that as_json includes that returning value in the returning hash. I have edited, maybe now is more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shadwell's answer is completely correct. However, I think that you could just use the `:methods` key like this:

```
def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:name, :last_name, :age], :methods => [:full_name])
end
```

Comment: That's much nicer than mine :)

Comment: Your comment is much nicer than my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(:only => [:name, :last_name, :age]).merge(
    { :full_name => self.full_name }.as_json
  )
end
```

This uses the default implementation for the model attributes and then merges in your derived attribute.